# Probability in Permutation

Tags: probability, permutations

A permutation of $1,2,3,\ldots,n$ is chosen at random. Then the probability that the numbers $1$ and $2$ appear as neighbours equals ______?
Options are

A) $\dfrac 1 n$

B) $\dfrac 2 n$

C) $\dfrac{1}{n-1}$

D) $\dfrac{1}{n-2}$

Comment: So what have you done so far? How many permutations of $1,\dots,n$ are there? How many where we have $\dots12\dots$? How many where we have $\dots21\dots$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $a_{i} = 1$, so $a_{i-1} = 2$ or $a_{i+1} = 2$.
If $1 \le i \le n$ , then number of valid positions $2(n-1)(n-2)!$, so the answer is :
$$\frac{2(n-1)(n-2)!}{n!}$$, answer ***B***

Comment: It seems to be right one .

Comment: But, how you determine that 2(n-1) possible position of 1,2 (according to question).

Comment: In the case where $1$ and $2$ are neighbors in that order, you have $n-1$ possible positions for this pair (the $1$ can be in position $1,2,\dots,n-1$. But for each of these positions, you can also permute the $1$ and the $2$, so you have to multiply by $2$. Finally, $(n-2)!$ is the number of permutations for the remaining numbers.

Comment: @CHANDAN you have: (n-2) position of $1$ when I could put $2$ from both sides and 2 position when I could put $2$ only from left or right side, so : $2(n-2)+2 = 2(n-1)$

Comment: Thanx now i get it properly

Answer (score 3):

Remove two numbers from the set. You have $n-2$ left. There are $(n-2)!$ ways to allocate them. For each such allocation there are two ways to order the removed numbers. Last thing, you have $n-1$ ways of putting these two together. Hence:
$$
\frac{2 (n-1)(n-2)!}{n!} = \frac{2}{n}
$$

Comment: Thanx, i got your point

Answer (score 0):

Let $E$ stand for the event that $|\pi(1)-\pi(2)|=1$, i.e. $1$ and $2$ end up as neighbours.

Let $R$ stand for the event that $\pi(1)\in\{1,n\}$, i.e. only one spot for a neighbor.

Then:

$$P(E)=P(E\mid R)P(R)+P(E\mid R^c)P(R^c)=\frac1{n-1}\frac2{n}+\frac2{n-1}\frac{n-2}{n}=\frac2{n}$$

---

**edit** (alternative, inspired by the neat outcome $\frac2{n}$):

Think of a round table with $n+1$ spots. Place the numbers $0,1,\dots,n$ randomly. Starting at (and also disregarding) the place where $0$ is seated you will yield a random permutation of $1,2,\dots,n$ by going clockwise from there. The place where $1$ is seated is flanked by $2$ spots and there are $n$ candidates for these spots. So the probability that $2$ is seated on one of these spots is $\frac2{n}$.